# Let $S=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=25\}$. Show that $|S|=|\Bbb R|$ by using the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S= \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=25\}$. Show that $|S|=|\Bbb R|$ by using the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Theorem; that is, by showing that there exists injective map from $S \to \Bbb R$ and vice versa.

I construct a map $f:\Bbb R \to S$ as $f(x)=(x, \sqrt{25-x^2})$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
I've shown that this is injective. In the other hand, for a map $g:S \to \Bbb R$, I've no idea yet.
For now, IMO, $g((x,y))=x$, but this is seems not injective.
Any idea? Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: Two ideas: * use your $g$ for nonnegative $x$ and a variant of $g$ for negative $x$ (remember that these maps don't have to be continuous or anything like that); or * use the presumably known fact that $\#\Bbb R = \#(\Bbb R^2)$.

Comment: watch out: your function f is not well-defined on $\mathbb{R}$, just on [0,5]. As a different approach, try to modify the function $x \mapsto e^{ix}$ that maps a real number to a point on the unit circle.

Comment: For a map $S\backslash\{(0,1)\}\to\mathbb{R}$, use a stereographic projection.